# How to close a window with Spec in Pharo

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, pharo, spec-ui

I have a Spec window with several controls. When I click on the Ok button I want the window to be closed.

```
| m |
m := DynamicComposableModel new.
m instantiateModels: #(text TextModel ok OkToolbar).
m ok okAction: [ self close ].
m openWithSpecLayout: (SpecLayout composed
    newColumn: [ : c | c add: #text ; add: #ok height: 30 ];
    yourself).
```

I have tried sending delete and close, but none worked. How can I close the window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this:

```
| m |
m := DynamicComposableModel new.
m instantiateModels: #(text TextModel ok OkToolbar).
m ok okAction: [ m window close ].
m openWithSpecLayout: (SpecLayout composed
    newColumn: [ : c | c add: #text ; add: #ok height: 30 ];
    yourself).
```